# Chrome Extension determine if installed from mobile Chrome Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Google offers the possibility to install a Chrome extension by browsing the chrome store on Mobile (iOS/Android). Once the user hits install, he will be shown a popup once he opens the Chrome browser on his desktop computer.

For analytics purposes, how can one determine that the extension was Installed through the mobile Chrome Store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you would be able to do that for a specific user/installation. 
chrome.runtime.onInstalled does not provide this kind of reason with the event.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-OnInstalledReason
If you want to know it for stats then I believe your best bet is setting up Google Analytics with your extension's Webstore listing and go with its device breakdown.